# solr - define 1:n relationship

Tags: search, solr

I want to import data from 1:n db relation i.e. Cars and CarParts tables.
Since I dont want to write a join over the the tables
(car id and name will be multiplied in the query and thus will be with a higher score in he query)
I am looking for the recommended way to represent in dataconfig and schema xml files 1:n connection.

Comment: Denormalize depending on your search scenarios http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign

Answer (score 0):

Multivalued fields can be used to solve this issue.

Your dataconfig may look something like:

```
...
<entity name="Cars" query="select carId, carName from Cars">

   <entity name="CarParts" query="select carPartName from CarParts 
                                    where carId = '${Cars.CarId}'">

  </entity>

</entity>
...
```

In your schema file, mark the field "carPartName" as multivalued.

```
<field name="carPartName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

The 1:n relationship is now handled such that, if a document is created for each "Car", then  the corresponding "Carparts" (which can be more than one) are also part of the same document.